# CMD/BATCH move all folders and subfolders

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I am looking for a way to move a folder including subfolders to a new location

old location: `C:\Users\test\OneDrive`

new location: `c:\new`

The command below moves all files in the root folder `C:\Users\test\OneDrive` to the new location, but all subfolders are missing

```
move C:\Users\Hiss\OneDrive\*.* c:\new
```

Comment: use `robocopy` with `/e /move` - https://ss64.com/nt/robocopy.html

Comment: Use `MOVE C:\Users\Hiss\OneDrive C:\new` remembering that if source or destination contain spaces to use double quotes, _(e.g. `MOVE "C:\Users\Hendrik Hiss\OneDrive" C:\new` or `MOVE C:\Users\Hiss\OneDrive "C:\new folder"`)._

Answer (score 1):

You can use two `for` statements (one for the files and one for the folders):

```
echo off
for %%a in ("%1\*") do move /y "%%~fa" %2
for /d %%a in ("%1\*") do move /y "%%~fa" %2
```

Put that in a batch file (e.g. MoveContents.bat), and run with parameters:

```
MoveContents.bat C:\Users\Hiss\OneDrive\ c:\new
```

Comment: Any idea why I would get "Access is denied"?  It's the same drive.

Comment: Only processes with elevated access can write to the root.